# django sort objects by number of friends who have them

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I have Ownership model, which has FK to User and Item. 
User has m2m to self, friends.

```
class Ownership:
    user = FK(User)
    item = FK(Item)

class User:
    friends = M2M(User)
```

I want to get Ownership objects for a user, sorted by the number of user's friends who have the same item. Is it possible in QuerySet at all, or should I go with raw SQL, and if so, what that SQL would look like?

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to do:

```
(with user u)

users_objects = sorted(Ownership.objects.filter(user=u), key=lambda x:Ownership.objects.filter(item=x.item, user__in=u.friends).count())
```